# How do I specify that I want my jsp-config directive to apply to all JSP pages served in our application?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jboss, config

We are using JBoss 7.1.3.Final with Java 6.  I would like to apply UTF-8 page encoding to all JSP pages served on our site, so I added this to our web.xml file

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

which results in the below error.

```
Message:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

StackTrace:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:581)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:397)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:198)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.makeJavaIdentifier(JspUtil.java:830)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.makeJavaIdentifier(JspUtil.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getServletClassName(JspCompilationContext.java:399)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getClassFileName(JspCompilationContext.java:580)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:438)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.isOutDated(Compiler.java:406)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:645)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
    ... 69 more
```

Although our pages are stored with the following file paths ...

```
project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/folder1/index.jsp
```

Our URL patterns do not end in .jsp.  In fact, they are just words (e.g. "/folder1/index").  However, when I tried this directive

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

my application although failed to start when I rebooted my server.  How do we specify that we want a directive to apply to all JSP pages that are served from our site?

Comment: I thought "*.jsp" patterns only apply to URLs that end in "*.jsp".  Although the files are named ".jsp" on my filesystem, the URLs that ultimately invoke those do not (they are just words, like '/dir1/path1").  Would ".jsp" apply to URLs that do not end in ".jsp"?

Comment: refer this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/265872

Comment: The JSP spec (2.3) says that you should use the URL patterns that resolve to JSPs. But it is unclear how that interferes with servlet-mapping elements.  You must have some servlet-mapping directives, do you, as your JSPs are not named like .jsp .

Comment: Refer this https://developer.jboss.org/thread/265872

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running a different version of JBoss (7.1.3) than what is referred to in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

using filter you can apply page encoding.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
    //                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        }

        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            String encodingParam = filterConfig.getInitParameter("encoding");
            if (encodingParam != null) {
                encoding = encodingParam;
            }
        }
```

Register this filter in web.xml

Comment: Thanks but addressing the question at hand, how do I write a URL pattern that applies to all URLs, given taht "<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>" doesn't seem to work?